# Can i use [(ngModel)] in every component when include FormsModule in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I use [(ngModel)] in every component when import FormsModule in app.module.ts

In `app.module.ts`

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Use in another component

In `view.component.html`

```
input type="text" ([ngModel])="UserName"
```

Actually, I use that but not give value.

Comment: If your app has only the app module. yes. but if your app has separate modules No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if that component (in which you want to use ngModel) is directly linked to `app.module`

Comment: You need to import `FormsModule` inside that `view` module to use `ngModel` in components which fall under `view` module.

Comment: It means I have to make view.module.ts inside the view module

Comment: In which `.module` `view.component.html` exists?

Comment: In the view component

Comment: And in which module have you declared `view.component`?

Comment: In the app, module, I have declared a view component